# How to set a style for the headers of a tab Item?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tabs

The problem is that when I do it as shown in the code I cannot change the text in each header without losing the fontsize.

I am using many tabs from the dragablz library and I need to make a default style for the headers which will define the font size and other attributes.

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">
        <dragablz:TabablzControl Margin="8" TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <dragablz:TabablzControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:DragablzItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDragableTabItemVerticalStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                </Style>
            </dragablz:TabablzControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TextBox FontSize="30">Hello</TextBox>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>

            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Tab No. 2" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem>
                <TextBlock FontSize="24">We Have Tearable Tabs!</TextBlock>
            </TabItem>
        </dragablz:TabablzControl>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `Header` property, you can use `HeaderTemplate`. If Header is simple text, it will get desired FontSize and Foreground. But it also can be replaced completely with some complex content

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter TextElement.FontSize="30" 
                                  TextElement.Foreground="Blue" 
                                  Content="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Tab No. 2" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
</TabItem>

<TabItem Header="Tab No. 2">
    <TextBlock FontSize="24">We Have Tearable Tabs!</TextBlock>
</TabItem>
```